# How to eliminate duplicate record in left join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a view named saledetailfortax and it will consist 13 columns. They are saledetaildate, saledetailtime, shopid, productid, unitid, expdate, batchno, mrp, totalprice, qty, looseqty, priceperunit and taxid.

My query is:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW saledetailfortax2 AS 
  select sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime, sd.shopid, sd.productid,
        sd.unitid, sd.expdate, sd.batchno, sd.mrp, sd.totalprice, sd.qty, 
        sd.looseqty, sd.unitprice as priceperunit, ord.taxid 
  from saledetail sd
  left JOIN distinctPriceperunit  ord
      ON  sd.productid = ord.productid
      AND sd.expdate = ord.expdate
      AND sd.batchno = ord.batchno
      AND sd.mrp = ord.mrp
      AND sd.unitprice = ord.priceperunit  
  where sd.saledetaildate >= '2016-04-01'
  order by  sd.saledetaildate , sd.saledetailtime
```

The problem is when there are two taxid with same productid , expdate , batchno ,
mrp and unitprice then there are two records comes with same thing.

Suppose in saledetail table a record consist same productid, expdate, batchno, mrp and unitprice, but the productid have two taxid in distinctPriceperunit table then when left join occure it comes out with two records. But there only one record show with either of two taxid.

So how to eliminate duplicate record .

View distinctpriceperunit (all are distinct values) :

SELECT DISTINCT od.productid, od.unitid, od.priceperunit, od.expdate, od.mrp, od.batchno, od.taxid
   FROM orderreceivedetail od
  ORDER BY od.productid, od.unitid, od.priceperunit, od.expdate, od.mrp, od.batchno, od.taxid;

TABLE saledetail
(
  saledetailid character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  saledetaildate date,
  saledetailtime timestamp without time zone,
  shopid integer,
  productid integer,
  qty integer,
  unitid integer,
  unitprice numeric,
  discperc numeric,
  discamt numeric,
  expdate date,
  mrp numeric,
  mfdate date,
  batchno character varying(50),
  totalprice numeric,
  isreturned boolean,
  userid integer,
  saleid character varying(20),
  isloose boolean,
  looseqty integer,
  CONSTRAINT saledetail_pkey PRIMARY KEY (saledetailid)
)

Comment: Could you please format the query in order to make it more readable. Furthermore, could you provide the definition of the tables.

Comment: Either a GROUP BY, or a correlated sub-query in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW saledetailfortax2 AS 
select sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime, sd.shopid, sd.productid,
       sd.unitid, sd.expdate, sd.batchno, sd.mrp, sd.totalprice, sd.qty, 
       sd.looseqty, sd.unitprice as priceperunit, MAX(ord.taxid) 
from saledetail sd
left JOIN distinctPriceperunit ord
    ON  sd.productid = ord.productid
    AND sd.expdate = ord.expdate
    AND sd.batchno = ord.batchno
    AND sd.mrp = ord.mrp
    AND sd.unitprice = ord.priceperunit  
where sd.saledetaildate >= '2016-04-01'
group by sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime, sd.shopid, sd.productid,
         sd.unitid, sd.expdate, sd.batchno, sd.mrp, sd.totalprice, sd.qty, 
         sd.looseqty, sd.unitprice
order by sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime
```

Correlated sub-query solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW saledetailfortax2 AS 
select sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime, sd.shopid, sd.productid,
       sd.unitid, sd.expdate, sd.batchno, sd.mrp, sd.totalprice, sd.qty, 
       sd.looseqty, sd.unitprice as priceperunit,
       (select max(taxid) from distinctPriceperunit ord
        WHERE sd.productid = ord.productid
          AND sd.expdate = ord.expdate
          AND sd.batchno = ord.batchno
          AND sd.mrp = ord.mrp
          AND sd.unitprice = ord.priceperunit)
from saledetail sd
where sd.saledetaildate >= '2016-04-01'
order by sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime
```

Comment: @Sagi, took some time typing.

Comment: I take that back:)

Comment: it did the trick for me, The Correlated sub-query solution. Thank you jarlh

Comment: @jarlh i have a doubt, in my idea when we left join a table with another then left table shows with records which condition satisfied. but why here there are more records than left table.

Comment: @Avinash, left join returns rows from left table even without condition satisfied. This correlated sub-query will never return more rows than the left join version. It can only return less rows!

Comment: @jarlh  can only one correlated sub-query used in a query

Comment: @Avinash, you can have any number of correlated sub-queries.

Comment: @jarlh   this query throws a ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.                                                                                            select sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime, sd.shopid, sd.productid,
       sd.unitid, sd.expdate, sd.batchno, sd.mrp, sd.totalprice, sd.qty, 
       sd.looseqty, 

       (select priceperunit from distinctPriceperunit ord
        WHERE sd.productid = ord.productid
          AND sd.expdate = ord.expdate
          AND sd.batchno = ord.batchno
          AND sd.mrp = ord.mrp ) as priceperunit,

Comment: (select max(taxid) from distinctPriceperunit ord
  WHERE sd.productid = ord.productid
  AND sd.expdate = ord.expdate
  AND sd.batchno = ord.batchno
  AND sd.mrp = ord.mrp ) as taxd

from saledetail sd
Where sd.saledetaildate <= '2016-03-31'
order by sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime

Comment: You have to make sure those correlated sub-queries NEVER return more than 1 row. (Using MAX() is one safe way.)

Comment: However, if you have two (or more) very similar correlated sub-queries, I suppose a left join with group by is a better solution. (Like my first code in my answer.)

Comment: @jarlh  yes that is the problem. it returns more than 1 row. If i use distinct then it will be ok or not

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GROUP BY these columns productid , expdate , batchno , mrp and unitprice.

Answer (score -1):

Use
    MAX(unitprice)

That will remove your duplications.